# AFNetworking JSON request with a boolean

Tags: iphone, ios, json, afnetworking

I'm trying to send a JSON request using AFNetworking and have a problem with making values be translated to the json form of `{"value": true}`. Instead, I'm getting: `{"value": 1}`

Here's basically how I'm creating the request:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request =
    [self.httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                  path:url
                            parameters:@{@"value": @YES}];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
    [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request ...];
    [operation start];
```

Am I missing something trivial here? :)

Comment: Since @YES is an NSNumber, NSJSONSerialization turns this to 0/1. I don't think there's a way other than @{@"value": (yesOrNo ? @"true" : @"false")} or using a different serialization class.

Comment: @TalBereznitskey Looks like my server's implementation that's expecting a boolean handles nicely a string value of "true"/"false"! If you'd paste that as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Short answer:**
Make sure you are running a recent version of [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). That's all I can see as the problem based on the code you've provided.

**Long answer:**
I've tried reproducing the issue you're describing with the most recent versions of [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and I could not. I dug into AFNetworking to see how the encoding of JSON is done. [AFHTTPClient.m:442](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/fa0fc535a149a35f4a69b4e082b1a8cccad0d002/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.m#L442) uses [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to encode JSON requests. I came up with the following code to test the issue:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@"value" : @YES} options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"Resulting JSON:\n\n%@\n", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

outputs:

```
{"value":true}
```

So `@YES` should do it. As a note, be sure **not** to use `@(YES)` in your code as it will output as a `1` instead of `true`.

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@"value" : @(YES)} options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"JSON:%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

outputs:

```
{"value":1}
```

With that I went through and tried to figure out how AFHTTPClient need to be configured to send out a bool as `1`/`0` instead of `true`/`false` and could not find any. Here's my networking code.

```
AFHTTPClient* httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://<SERVER HERE>"]];
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *jsonRequest = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/" parameters:@{@"value": @YES}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *jsonOperation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:jsonRequest success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Success");
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Failure");
}];
[jsonOperation start];
```

Comment: You're correct, this indeed should just work. Turns out that my problem is resulting from my Core Data model which for some reason doesn't retain the "boolness" of my boolean property :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also, I've created a question about that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14029473/573

Comment: This was my problem: "As a note, be sure not to use @(YES) in your code as it will output as a 1 instead of true." SO FRUSTRATING.

Comment: there is no setParameterEncoding in Afnetworking 3.0, how u handle this now?

Answer (score 3):

Since @YES is an NSNumber, NSJSONSerialization turns this to 0/1.

I don't think there's a way other than `@{@"value": (yesOrNo ? @"true" : @"false")}` or using a different serialization class.

Comment: @YES is a `NSNumber`, but it's created based on a BOOL value (it's equivalent to `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`. And the `NSNumber` instance will "remember" the type with which it was created, so the `NSJSONSerialization` will output the right thing. You can check the value returned by sending the `objCType` message to the `NSNumber` instance, and you'll see that `@YES` is different than `@1` (or `@(YES)`, for that matter).

Comment: "Note that number objects do not necessarily preserve the type they are created with." From the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

For people who might be running into this issue, there's another reason why it might be happening.

Make sure you set the `parameterEncoding` property of your `AFHTTPClient` subclass to `AFJSONParameterEncoding`, otherwise you'll run into the issue of NSNumber's initialization value not being correctly detected, and will see 0s and 1s being output instead by the encoder.

See [this](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ#how-do-i-send-json-parameters-in-my-request) for reference as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the subclass of HTTPClient. Instead of:

```
self.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

try with:

```
$self.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, I am sending the @YES but the services give me fail, so I create and string of a json and create an jsonObject like this:

```
NSString* paramsString = @"{";
NSString* appending = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\":%@,", KEY_CHECKED, (checked ? @"true" : @"false")];
paramsString = [paramsString stringByAppendingString: appending];
paramsString = [paramsString stringByAppendingString:@"}"];
id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[paramsString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
```

Use this object for send the post with AFNetworking

```
[self postParameters:object];
```

for me works!