# Core Data Boolean property NSNumber doesn't remember it's boolean

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a model with a property that looks like this:

[image]

When I set its value, for example:

```
model.isResolved = @YES;
```

The NSNumber that's kept inside the model "forgets" that it's a boolean:

```
NSLog(@"%@", strcmp([self.isResolved objCType], @encode(BOOL)) == 0 ? @"equal" : @"different");
```

Prints "different". What is up with that?

Comment: You might try a valueForKey: instead of a plain getter.  You may just be comparing a faulted object.

Comment: @CodaFi what's a "faulted object"? Why does that make a difference?

Comment: Faults are Core Data's major fetching optimization.  Instead of going and getting the requested property on a managed object every time, it returns a dummy faulted object that shows that the record exists, but it doesn't actually go through the expensive process of retrieving all of the object's properties and it's hash.  Using valueForKey: guarantees a fetch that has no faults.

Comment: @CodaFi: It does not matter if you call `self.xxx` or `[self valueForKey:@"xxx"]`. In either case a fault will be fired for `self` (if necessary) and the attributes value returned.

Answer (score 3):

> What is up with that?

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Note that number objects do not necessarily preserve the type they are created with.

That's another inconsistency-for-optimization in Cocoa.

Comment: +1, but I'm not buying it.  There should at least be some cases where a non-faulted core data property will remember it's type, especially if the option to keep primitives around as primitives is on.

Comment: @CodaFi Thanks. But why? Really, `YES` is just `(unsigned char)1`.

Comment: Something about it seems fishy to me.  I'll run some tests in the morning and ping you.  Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 2):

Core Data dynamically generates getter and setter methods for all attributes (and relationships) of managed object classes. These accessor methods are different from the "usual" @synthesized accessor methods which are backed up by an instance variable.

In particular, if you set an attribute and then retrieve the attributes value again, you can get an object that is ***different from the "original" object***. The following test shows this, `foo1` is an instance of a Core Data entity with the Boolean attribute "show":

```
NSNumber *yes = @YES;
NSLog(@"yes = %p, type = %s", yes, [yes objCType]);
foo1.show = yes;
NSNumber *val = foo1.show;
NSLog(@"val = %p, type = %s", val, [val objCType]);
```

*Output:*

```
yes = 0x16e595c, type = c
val = 0x744c150, type = i
```

So even if you set the attribute to a *c = char* encoded number, the getter method returns a *i = int* encoded number.

This test was done in the iOS Simulator. Interestingly the same test, running on OS X 64-bit, returns a *c = char* encoded number.

Therefore, the actual encoding of Boolean and other scalar attributes in Core Data objects should probably be treated as an implementation detail of Core Data.

If you need to check the Core Data type as defined in the model, you can use the objects entity description instead of `objCType`:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [foo1 entity];
NSAttributeDescription *attr = [[entity attributesByName] objectForKey:@"show"];
NSAttributeType type = [attr attributeType];
if (type == NSBooleanAttributeType) {
    NSLog(@"Its a Boolean!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its stored as a NSNumber - by the way @YES is creating a NSNumber like

`[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`

so to get the bool back out you do:

`[isResolved boolValue]`

(you can avoid this by ticking the Use Scalar Properties when you create your models)