# Why isnt BOOLEAN attribute of a Core Data entity__NSCFNumber and not __NSCFBoolean?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsnumber

In Core Data Entities, we have to wrap primitive numbers (char,int,float,double and BOOL) to there Class cluster NSNumber.

Although the core data user interface let's us specify a type where I specifically mentio it as BOOLEAN and default type to YES or NO.

Now when I get a JSON-converted-NSDictionary from an API call I try to store a boolean true or false into this attribute.

However I have noticed, while printing the class of both the core data entity and the json-dictionary's corresponding value for the key in the debugger console, that

Core Data entity's NSNumber wrapped attributes class is __NSCFNumber and for the dictionary's value for the key is __NSCFBoolean.

I know about the class cluster pattern and I understand that we have subclasses under NSNumber whose actual objects are created when numberWithInt or numberWithBool are called and are represented as the one umbrella term NSNumber.

But what I did not understand was, why didnt the debugger show Core Data entities bool attribute as __NSCFBoolean ?

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/14030911/1187415, where I have tried to answer a similar question. The interesting thing is that the behaviour is different on iOS and OS X.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Core Data Boolean property NSNumber doesn't remember it's boolean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029473/core-data-boolean-property-nsnumber-doesnt-remember-its-boolean)